# How to get and modify/replace/remove an event listener

Tags: events, sapui5

I am extending a SAP standard Fiori App. They have one method for creating a [`sap.m.ViewSettingsDialog`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ViewSettingsDialog.html). Now I am adding my own [`sap.m.ViewSettingsItem`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ViewSettingsItem.html) containing some [`sap.m.ViewSettingsFilterItem`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ViewSettingsFilterItem.html)s.

Now I want to modify/replace/remove the Listener on the event `confirm`, because I can not save the values from the bound ODataModel onto the CusomObject the way SAP does.

My attempt was to enhance their confirm method. I searched SCN, Stackoverflow and the SAPUI5 API for a getter for eventhndlers, I did not found anything. So how can I get that object?

For further understanding of my problem underneath it:

**Their confirm method:**

```
              confirm: function (oEvent) {
            //reset the buffered filter arrays
            self.filterValueArray.length = 0;              
            var p = oEvent.getParameters(),
                aFilters,
                oCallback;

            for (var i = 0 ; i < p.filterItems.length; i++) {
                if (p.filterItems[i] instanceof sap.m.ViewSettingsCustomItem) { // custom control filter
                    oCallback = p.filterItems[i].getCustomData()[0].getValue();
                    aFilters = oCallback.apply(this, [p.filterItems[i].getCustomControl()]);
                    if (aFilters) {
                        // the filter could be an array of filters or a single filter so we transform it to an array
                        if (!Array.isArray(aFilters)) {
                            aFilters = [aFilters];
                        }
                        self.filterValueArray = self. filterValueArray.concat(aFilters);
                    }
                } else if (p.filterItems[i] instanceof sap.m.ViewSettingsItem) { // standard filter
                    aFilters = p.filterItems[i].getCustomData()[0].getValue();
                    if (aFilters) {
                        // the filter could be an array of filters or a single filter so we transform it to an array
                        if (!Array.isArray(aFilters)) {
                            aFilters = [aFilters];
                        }
                        self.filterValueArray = self.filterValueArray.concat(aFilters);
                    }
                }
            }

            // apply filters to the table binding
            self._updateList(self.getList().getBinding("items"));

            // update info toolbar
            self.getView().byId("infoBarToolbar").setVisible((self.filterValueArray.length > 0) ? true: false);
            self.getView().byId("infoBarFilter").setText((self.filterValueArray.length > 0) ? p.filterString: "");  

            // save expiry filter state for the "cancel" action
            self._setExpiryFilterState();                       
        }
```

**My added Filter**

```
var oBindingInfo = {
            path: "/PathToTheKeyValuePairs",
            template: new sap.m.ViewSettingsItem({
                key: "{Key}",
                text: "{Value}",
                customData: new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
                    key: "callback",
                    value: function(oControl) {
                        debugger; //getting the data and creating filter here
                    }

                 //That would be the SAP Solution Sap does with hardcoded Filter

                    // key: "filter",
                    // value: new sap.ui.model.Filter("TargetAttribute", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "{Key}") //fixme It takes the string and no binding info
                })
            })
        };

        var oMyCustomFilter = new sap.m.ViewSettingsFilterItem({
            key: "myCustomFilter",
            text: self.resourceBundle.getText("myFilterName"),
        });


        oMyCustomFilter.bindAggregation("items", oBindingInfo);
        this.filterDialog.addFilterItem(oMyCustomFilter);
```

Comment: I have done something bad. I just overwrote the confirm on the Eventprovider. (private attribute). I am still searching for a proper solution..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `attachEvent` or `attachEventOnce` to add a function to be called additionally on the `confirm` event:

```
oDialog.attachEventOnce("confirm", fnAfterConfirm);
```

where `oDialog` is the `ViewSettingsDialog`.

See the API guide to [**`sap.ui.base.EventProvider`**](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.EventProvider.html).

Comment: Does not work, since the confirm method throws an Exception. It can not handle my objects.

Comment: Maybe you can look at the documentation on “sap.m.ViewSettingsItem”. There is the possibility to add an event “itemPropertyChanged” when a particular value is changed.  This might allow you to manipulate the set of filtered items before it reaches the standard code.